# Early migration from aurelia-cli to webpack

Tags: webpack, aurelia

let's say I wanted to migrate from the  [Contact manager tutorial](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/contact-manager-tutorial) to [webpack](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/contact-manager-tutorial) without starting over, what changes do I have to make in order to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Copy your `src` folder, make sure you install the needed dependencies in your `package.json` file and then you should be good to go. Out-of-the-box Webpack and CLI are pretty close, except the CLI currently is RequireJS. Migrating should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: sadly this doesn't appear to be true, at last not with typescript involved which I realize I didn't specify. Of course that might just be the difference between skeletons, and the cli, not sure, but since I'm not that familliar with any of it.